# Dangers of installing a bonding plug

Tags: grounding-and-bonding

I have a generator that, I was told, has a floating neutral, so I purchased a ground neutral bonding plug because it is required in order to use the Soft Start plug.
The generators motor started smoking after I started it.
Was this caused because maybe the generator is already bonded?

Comment: What make and model is the generator in question?

Comment: Is it possible the generator had a pre-existing problem, such as a hot-ground fault, that you were unaware of? When it's running is there 0 volts between neutral and ground?  On your neutral ground bonding plug, is only the neutral and ground shunted?  Does it have a breaker on the generator?

Comment: If the generator already has a neutral-ground bond, bonding again will have no effect. Unlikely to be that the bonding plug was the problem as a problem should have tripped the breaker. Most likely, the problem you saw was unrelated.